# How to prevent my React child component from fetching data on every re-render/mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'll be posting a fair amount of code so I'll first give a conceptual introduction to the question.

[image]

Above is a work in progress regarding a Next.js application that is visualizing the state of my Philips Hue lights, by talking to the API of the Hue Bridge device. The top row allows to select a light group which then only shows the lights in that group as well as the scenes for the group.

My question is related to the scenes part. The bridge API has no "details" call to get the scenes for a specific group, instead it's a call to get every single scene of all groups combined. It has a big response, but I'm calling it only once after which filtering by group happens client-side. I can confirm from network monitoring that the "all scenes" call is indeed called only once.

Based on this scene data and the actively selected light group, I render "Scene" child components, the blocks with colored dots below the lights.

The scene child component makes a scene details network call, which is needed to fetch the light state of the scene (which is light group specific). In the screenshot example, this would mean 20 individual network calls.

This is as expected, but I want to make such a detail call only once per group-scene combination. Right now, every time I select a different light group (top row) all the scene child components re-render and fetch the scene details calls again, even if they were loaded before.

```
return (
    <>
      <div className="group-list">
        {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        {isLoading && <p>loading groups...</p>}
        <Group
          key="all"
          onSelectGroup={setActiveGroup}
          group={null}
          activeGroup={activeGroup}
        />
        {groups &&
          groups.map((group) => (
            <Group
              group={group}
              key={group.num}
              onSelectGroup={setActiveGroup}
              activeGroup={activeGroup}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
      <LightList group={groupLights} groupNum={activeGroup} />
      {activeGroup && <SceneList groupNum={activeGroup} />}
    </>
  );
```

Above is the code that embeds the **SceneList** component. Of particular relevance is how a change of group is passed in as a prop, so that the SceneList component filters to show only the scenes belonging to the group.

```
import { memo, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { HueScene } from "types/hue";
import Scene from "@components/Scene/Scene";
import "@styles/components/scenelist.css";

interface SceneListProps {
  groupNum: string | null;
}

const ENDPOINT = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HUE_API_ADDRESS}/api/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HUE_API_USERNAME}/scenes`;

const SceneList = memo(function SceneList({ groupNum }: SceneListProps) {
  const [sceneData, setSceneData] = useState(null);
  const [scenes, setScenes] = useState<HueScene[]>();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const fetchScenesData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(ENDPOINT);
      const data = await response.json();

      if (data[0]?.error) {
        setError(data[0]?.error?.description || "Error from Hue V1 API");
      } else {
        setSceneData(data);
        setError(null);
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(err.message || "Error loading scene data from Hue Bridge.");
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const normalizeScenesData = (data: Record<string, any>): HueScene[] => {
    return Object.entries(data)
      .map(([num, sceneData]) => ({
        ...sceneData,
        num,
      }))
      .filter((scene) => scene.group === groupNum);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!error) fetchScenesData();
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sceneData && !isLoading) {
      setScenes(normalizeScenesData(sceneData));
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [groupNum, isLoading]);

  return (
    <div className="scene-list">
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      {isLoading && <p>loading scenes...</p>}
      {scenes && (
        <div>
          <h2>Scenes</h2>

          {scenes.map((scene) => (
            <Scene key={scene.num} scene={scene} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});

export default SceneList;
```

Above is the SceneList component itself. It fetches all scenes data (only once) but will filter the set based on the group prop change. This component seems to work as expected in terms of render behavior and network calls.

```
import { HueScene } from "types/hue";
import "@styles/components/scene.css";
import { memo, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { calculateSceneLampColor } from "@utils/color";

interface SceneProps {
  scene: HueScene;
}

const Scene = memo(function Scene({ scene }: SceneProps) {
  const { num, name, group } = scene;

  const [sceneColors, setSceneColors] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const ENDPOINT_POST = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HUE_API_ADDRESS}/api/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HUE_API_USERNAME}/groups/${group}/action`;
  const ENDPOINT_GET = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HUE_API_ADDRESS}/api/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HUE_API_USERNAME}/scenes/${num}`;

  const cacheColors = useRef();

  const fetchSceneData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(ENDPOINT_GET);
      const data = await response.json();

      if (data[0]?.error) {
        setError(data[0]?.error?.description || "Error from Hue V1 API");
      } else {
        cacheColors.current = normalizeSceneData(data);
        setError(null);
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(err.message || "Error loading scene data from Hue Bridge.");
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const normalizeSceneData = (data: Record<string, any>) => {
    var colors: string[] = [];

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data?.lightstates)) {
      colors[parseInt(key)] = calculateSceneLampColor(value);
    }

    return colors;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cacheColors.current === undefined) {
      fetchSceneData();
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  async function recallScene(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const bodyData = { scene: num };
    try {
      const response = await fetch(ENDPOINT_POST, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyData),
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (data[0]?.error) {
        console.error("Error:", data[0].error.description);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      {!isLoading && (
        <button className="scene" onClick={recallScene}>
          <div className="scene-name">{name}</div>
          <div className="scene-colors">
            {cacheColors.current &&
              cacheColors.current.map((sceneColor, light) => (
                <div
                  key={group + "-" + light + "-" + num + "-" + sceneColor}
                  className="scene-color"
                  style={{ background: sceneColor }}
                ></div>
              ))}
          </div>
        </button>
      )}
    </>
  );
}, didSceneStateChange);

function didSceneStateChange(prevProps: any, nextProps: any) {
  return JSON.stringify(prevProps) === JSON.stringify(nextProps);
}

export default Scene;
```

Above is the problematic Scene child component. As explained, it makes its own network call to get scene details. The problem is that this component does it on every re-render/re-mount whilst the results of the network call will never change for the specific group-scene combination.

I've tried **keys**, **memo** and **useRef** to avoid this, but none of these strategies seem to work. I suspect that due to the group filtering, these child components get destroyed and recreated from scratch every single time, but I'm unsure how to avoid that in this particular situation.

Comment: Interesting, let's put some context on this. The issue you're facing with the Scene child components making network calls on every re-render or re-mount is likely related to how React re-renders components when their props or state change. In your case, when the groupNum prop changes, the Scene child components re-render, leading to new network calls for the same scene details. To avoid unnecessary network calls, you can implement a caching mechanism in your SceneList component.

Comment: This looks like a very cool project! Do you have plans on open-sourcing the project, or releasing it somewhere?

Comment: @EricB Yes, will release this as open source somewhere near the end of this year.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a dry guess here but caching would help or be a start to solving the problem, making some adjustments you could perhaps try or mess around with the example.

```
import { memo, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { HueScene } from "types/hue";
import Scene from "@components/Scene/Scene";
import "@styles/components/scenelist.css";

interface SceneListProps {
  groupNum: string | null;
}

const ENDPOINT = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HUE_API_ADDRESS}/api/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HUE_API_USERNAME}/scenes`;

const SceneList = memo(function SceneList({ groupNum }: SceneListProps) {
  const [sceneData, setSceneData] = useState(null);
  const [scenes, setScenes] = useState<HueScene[]>();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  // Cache scene details based on groupNum
  const sceneDetailsCache = new Map<string, HueScene>();

  const fetchScenesData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(ENDPOINT);
      const data = await response.json();

      if (data[0]?.error) {
        setError(data[0]?.error?.description || "Error from Hue V1 API");
      } else {
        setSceneData(data);
        setError(null);
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(err.message || "Error loading scene data from Hue Bridge.");
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const normalizeScenesData = (data: Record<string, any>): HueScene[] => {
    return Object.entries(data)
      .map(([num, sceneData]) => ({
        ...sceneData,
        num,
      }))
      .filter((scene) => scene.group === groupNum);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!error) fetchScenesData();
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sceneData && !isLoading) {
      const filteredScenes = normalizeScenesData(sceneData);

      // Cache scene details based on groupNum
      filteredScenes.forEach((scene) => {
        if (!sceneDetailsCache.has(scene.num)) {
          sceneDetailsCache.set(scene.num, scene);
        }
      });

      setScenes(filteredScenes);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [groupNum, isLoading]);

  return (
    <div className="scene-list">
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      {isLoading && <p>loading scenes...</p>}
      {scenes && (
        <div>
          <h2>Scenes</h2>

          {scenes.map((scene) => (
            <Scene key={scene.num} scene={sceneDetailsCache.get(scene.num) || scene} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});

export default SceneList;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, getting late here so will try this tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Update: tried your code. Unfortunately it seems that the caching strategy does not prevent the refetching of scene details. I suspect that the SceneList as a whole is unmounted and remounted upon group change (see first section of code in my question) thus destroying and recreating the cache each time.

Comment: Note that for now I've deprioritized this feature. It's only purpose was to create those little scene color dots. The network cost is very high to achieve this but I also discovered another issue: the order of the scene dots returned by the Bridge hardware do not match the actual light order, which makes for a confusing visualization. Still wanted to thank you for spending time on this and upvoted your answer.